# UIView with transparent in middle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, transparent

[image]

Is it possible to create such a `UIView` fill with color, but in the middle is transparent?

I'm thinking about to create **5** `UIView`s here. Just wondering is it possible to accomplish by using only ONE `UIView`

Comment: [CAShapeLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Check out my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141081/uiview-drawrect-draw-the-inverted-pixels-make-a-hole-a-window-negative-space/32941652#32941652

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Duncan C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205185/duncan-c), I get to know where should I start, then I found [CALayer with transparent hole in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512761/calayer-with-transparent-hole-in-it).

```
UIBezierPath *overlayPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.bounds];
UIBezierPath *transparentPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(60, 120, 200, 200)];
[overlayPath appendPath:transparentPath];
[overlayPath setUsesEvenOddFillRule:YES];

CAShapeLayer *fillLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
fillLayer.path = overlayPath.CGPath;
fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
fillLayer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:20/255.0 blue:147/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:fillLayer];
```

Make use of 2 `UIBezierPath`, then fill with color that I want *(in my question is pink color)*, then add as sublayer

Comment: If anyone know , How to transparent uiview with touches began any touches moved method..Please help me.

Comment: @milanpatel, don't post a new question as a comment on somebody else's thread. Create your own question.

Answer (score 0):

You create a view as subclass of UIView and add these codes:
In YourView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YourView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect rectForClearing;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *overallColor;

@end
```

In YourView.m

```
#import "YourView.h"

@implementation NBAMiddleTransparentView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder // support init from nib
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRef ct = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ct, self.overallColor.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(ct, self.bounds);
    CGContextClearRect(ct, self.rectForClearing);
}

@end
```

Using:

```
yourView.overallColor = [UIColor redColor];
yourView.rectForClearing = CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible. You could attach a mask layer to your view's layer, and "punch out" the center portion of the mask. It would actually be quite easy.

Comment: This comment needs some elaboration on how to add a mask and "punch" it out